# Missing menu options on my Meta Business Manager preventing me from requesting Facebook Graph API permission. Any solutions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-manager

I want to request permission from another user to use Graph API to access their ad info.  When I searched for how to do that, I was directed to go to my Meta Business Manager.  My Meta Business Manager does not have Users, Pelple, Partners, Assets, Paid Partnerships, Busienss Info, or Business settings in any menu.

I found a an instruction to add a primary page to my MBS but since I don't have the referenced menu items to click, I cannot even do that.

Here is my MBS screen shot.

[image]

Here is the Settings Menu Screen shot.

[image]

What do I need to do to get full functionality described in the various articles on how to request permission from another user to get access to their page ad data?

I was expecting to see a menu like this.

[image]

Thanks,